# How to make a fully functioning local version of wordpress? (Mac)

Tags: wordpress, localhost, local

Thanks in advance.

I've created a MAMP server and I've installed wordpress.  I can create and edit pages, and I have most of the functionality of a live site.  I can download the themes and plugins that I want and manually put them in the content folder, which was fine with me, but I can't put any files up.  It tells me that wordpress can't move files to its folders, which are located in Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/...

Comment: is it a problem with permission? wordpress should not have any constrain with folders.

Comment: The error message is this: “uploadpicture.png” has failed to upload due to an error
The uploaded file could not be moved to /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2011/12.  I'm guessing that it is a permission problem, but I have no idea on how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

try this linux command, I am not a mac user, but this should work in linux system.

```
chmod -R 777  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wordpress/wp-content/
```

Comment: This worked for me, except that the -R bit had to come before 777. So... chmod -R 777 dir/path/to/local/site

Answer (score 0):

I am also not a mac user. But these links may help to solve your problem.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions#Permission_Scheme_for_WordPress

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what went wrong, but a clean reinstall of Wordpress did the trick. All of your advice would have worked for almost every other person, so good job!